# Probability Counting Question

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I am still new to probability and am trying some counting problems
The question I am trying to solve is
A carton contains 10 balls. 3 of these are coloured black the rest blue.
Balls are drawn without replacement.
What is the probability that **at least one** of the selected balls is coloured black?

My attempt so far is

$$\frac{\binom{3}{1}\binom{7}{2}}{\binom{10}{4}} + \frac{\binom{3}{2}\binom{7}{1}}{\binom{10}{4}} + \frac{\binom{3}{3}\binom{7}{0}}{\binom{10}{4}}$$

My worry is I am getting the **at least part wrong**

Answer (score 2):

The better approach is to calculate the probability that *none* of the selected balls are black, then take 1.0 minus that probability.

The probability that the first ball is not black is $7/10$; given that case, then the probability the second ball is not black is $6/9$; and finally for the third case $5/8$.

$1 - 7/10*6/9*5/8 = 17/24$.

Comment: But would a combination be suitable in this instance ?? I like the above approach but my college professor loves his combinations :/

Comment: If you "need" to use combinations (or factorials), here's the answer (and I'll let you justify it):  $1 - (10-3)!/(7-3)! * (10-3)!/10!$.

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun: David G. Stork has presented the reasoning, kguler has identified the distribution that applies to your problem. Here is a simulation approximation ( reassuring consistent but no so nice as 17/24 derived):

```
tab = Table[
   RandomSample[Join[ConstantArray[1, 3], ConstantArray[0, 7]], 
    3], {1000000}];
Length@Cases[tab, {___, 1, ___}]/1000000.
```

or

```
Length@Pick[tab, Total@# >= 1 & /@ tab]/1000000.
```

yield 0.707966.